# Export MSSQL table records to MySQL in .sql file

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, database-migration

i've a MSSQL database and trying to migrate to MySQL database.. the problem is when I using MySQL WorkBench, some table records in my MSSQL database is not migrated (there is an error and MySQL Workbench not responding).. is there any tools to export MSSQL table records into SQL file that compatible to be executed in MySQL?

Comment: This isn't exporting, this is *scripting*. It won't work either, since every database product has its own syntax quirks and types. *No* database follows the full SQL Standard. That's why you get the errors. Post the errors if you want to modify the file. It's a lot easier though to use SSIS to transfer the data directly from one database to another, or add MySQL as a linked server and copy the data directly.

Comment: You can use the Export Data Wizard in SSMS to copy the data from SQL Server to MySQL easily, provided the target tables already exist. You can save the package generated by the wizard for later use, eg to run it on a schedule through SQL Server Agent

Comment: As for *migration*, you'll have to find workarounds for quite a lot of missing features, like analytic and windowing functions, datetimeoffset, no nvarchar support (it's varchar with a UTF8 encoding on MySQL), no sequences, no rowversion type, etc, etc. And no real backup, unless you buy a MySQL Enterprise license or compile the enterprise code so you can get mysqlbackup

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i've succeed create table creation script using mysql workbench.. the problem is when migrating the table records. i have several tables with a lot of records (table with largest records has 300k records in the table).. i'm trying to find a way to export the records to a file so i can migrate the database to MySQL without connect to a network.. i'm thinking to use bcp but i never use it.. is there any bcp tutorial to export all tables in MSSQL database?

Answer (score 2):

Both `T-SQL` and `MySQL` and support `VALUES` clause. So, right click on the database and select `Generate scripts` from `Tasks`:

[image]

Then you can choose objects:

[image]

and then make sure you have selected to get the data, too:

[image]

You can even get the schema and change it a little bit to match the `MySQL` syntax.

For small amount of data this is pretty cool. If you are exporting large tables it will be better to use another tool. For example, using `bcp` you can export your data in `CSV` format and then import it in the `MySQL` database.